# MySQL выборка одной строки (вместо нескольких) со сходными значениями из списка. Как?

Tags: php, выборка, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Сейчас постараюсь свою задачу перенести на пример. Может быть то, что я хотел бы узнать можно объяснить по-другому, но я не знаю как :)
Есть город, в городе есть улицы (каждая называется по порядковому номеру, т.е. ул1, ул2 и т.д.)
В гроде идет стройка, и улицы застраиваются домами. На любой улице могут быть дома, а могут и не быть.
В базе таблица (houses) с построенные домами:

```
ID  |  house_no  |  street_no
```

Вот теперь мне нужен запрос, который выводит улицу, если на ней есть хотя бы один дом. Интересуют улицы с 15 по 27

```
SELECT street_no FROM houses WHERE street_no >= 15 AND street_no <= 27
```

Все работает, он выводит улицы с домами. Но, если на улице стоит 5 домов, то он выводит эту улицу 5 раз подряд.
Можно ли сделать запрос, исходя из этой таблицы, чтобы он эту улицу выводил ОДИН раз, не смотря на количество домов на ней?
Надеюсь понятно пояснил.
Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

```
SELECT DISTINCT street_no FROM houses WHERE street_no >= 15 AND street_no <= 27
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: А можно ли как-то добавить лимит на этот запрос, касаемо вывода одной улицы? То есть - вот есть в sql такая штука, как LIMIT 3, например, т.е. он нам показывает 3 записи из ВСЕЙ выборки. Возможно ли установить такой лимит на выбрку, касаемо наших улиц? Т.е. показывать одну улицу максимум 3 раза (вместо одного, как сейчас), даже если на ней 25 домов. Спасибо!